# spark scala - UDF usage for creating new column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I need to create a new column called `hash_id` from `uid` column of my dataframe, Below is my code:

```
//1.Define a hashing function
def calculate_hashid (uid: String) : BigInteger ={

      val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
      val ha = new BigInteger( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(uid.getBytes)), 16).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10000))
      return ha

    }

//2.Convert function to UDF
val  calculate_hashidUDF = udf(calculate_hashid)

//3.Apply udf on spark dataframe
val userAgg_Data_hashid = userAgg_Data.withColumn("hash_id", calculate_hashidUDF($"uid"))
```

I am getting error at `udf(calculate_hashid)` saying

> missing arguments for the method calculate_hashid(string)

I have gone through many examples online but could not resolve it, what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your `udf` as

```
val  calculate_hashidUDF = udf[String, BigInteger](calculate_hashidUDF)
```

You can also rewrite your udf as

```
def calculate_hashidUDF = udf(((uid: String) => {
  val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
  new BigInteger( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(uid.getBytes)), 16).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10000))
}): String => BigInteger)
```

Or even without return type

```
def calculate_hashidUDF = udf((uid: String) => {
  val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
  new BigInteger( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(uid.getBytes)), 16).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10000))
})
```